# Angularjs modal not running code when closing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am a total AngularJS beginner, and I'm having a hard time getting a modal to behave like I want it to.
The problem in short is this: the code within the ".then" part of the modal is being run when opening the modal, not when closing it. See further explanation below my code.
I have a button in my index.html that calls a function:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addModal()" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Add account</span>
                </button>
```

My controller definition looks like this:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$http', '$modal',
 'ModalService', function ($scope, $http, $modal, ModalService)
```

My addModal function within MyController looks like this:

```
$scope.addModal = function () {
    console.log("addModal");

    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: "/addAccount.html",
        controller: "addController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        console.log('asd')
        modal.close.then(function(result) {
            console.log("Modal closed");
            $scope.settings = {};
            $scope.settings.balance = 0;
            $scope.settings.runningTotals = 0;
            $scope.settings.firstName = result.first;
            $scope.settings.lastName = result.last;
            $scope.settings.address = result.add;
            $scope.settings.postcode = result.post;
            $scope.settings.telephone = result.tele;
            $scope.settings.pin = result.pin;


            var json = JSON.stringify($scope.settings);
            console.log(json);
            console.log("Clicked button");

            return $http.post("http://abcmoneygroup.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc/createAccount", json);
        });
    });
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service) service to create modals. 
My modalcontroller looks like this:

```
app.controller('addController', ['$scope','close', '$element', function ($scope, close, $element) {

$scope.first = null;
$scope.last = null;
$scope.add = null;
$scope.post = null;
$scope.tele = null;
$scope.pin = null;

$scope.close = function () {
    console.log('close called')

    close({
        formfirstName: $scope.first,
        formLastName: $scope.last,
        formAddress: $scope.add,
        formPostCode: $scope.post,
        formTelephone: $scope.tele,
        formPin: $scope.pin
    }, 500);

};

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $element.modal('hide');

        close({

        }, 500);
    };
```

}]);

Finally addAccount.html contains this button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="close()" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>Save new account</span>
                </button>
```

My issue is that when I click "add account"-button the first time, my modal appears. In the console I see two lines: "addModal" and "asd".
After I have filled out a form in addAccount.html, I then click the "Save new account"-button. The modal then closes, and in the console I see the following line: "close called". **Why isn't the Http.post request being initated now?**

If I now click the "Add account"-button again, the modal opens, and I see the following lines in the console:

- addModal
- Modal closed
- {"balance":0,"runningTotals":0}
- Clicked button
- asd

To conclude, I am wondering why the code within the ".then"-part of my ModalService is being initated every time I open the modal, rather than every time I close it. Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: should use showModal().result.then?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Where would you put it though? Still inside $scope.addModal? 
I tried a couple of places, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of angular ui bootstrap result (Type: promise) is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed.
To make your code look cleaner i would suggest you to declare a variable `modalInstance`
and then use result to resolve or reject the promise

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {

  console.log(result);

}, function () {

  console.log('modal dismissed');

});
```

Comment: When I simply do var modalInstance = ModalService.showModal({....)}, and then do modalInstance.result.then(function){...} the console tells me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". 
Do I have to include $modalInstance in the controller definition? This gives an error that says " Error: Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance"
Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: OP isn't using angular-ui-bootstrap. Link to service used is in question

Comment: I might have included that as well, my module definition is like this:
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angularModalService']);

Can that lead to issues?

Comment: @jogorm If you are using ui bootstrap then you should stick the doc https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal and my solution will help.

Comment: @amanpurohit Yeah, you're probably right. I tried that before angularModalService, but gave lots of problems as well.  That's not related to this issue though, so thanks. Will try again :)